# Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_transaction()

Tags: 6, database

I am new to drupal. In an attempt to achieve transaction, I get this fatal error. I am using drupal 6.22 and MySQL. `db_query()` and all the other database related functions are working fine, but `db_transaction()` alone fails. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

```
$transaction = db_transaction();

try {
       $result = db_query($query);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
       $transaction->rollback();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no fuction `db_transaction()` for Drupal 6 (see [Drupal 6 API search](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/db_transaction)).

It **is** available for Drupal 7 though: [db_transaction()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_transaction/7)

Comment: so, is there any way to achieve transaction in drupal 6?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by Berdir in his answer

Answer (score 2):

The DB API in Drupal 6 does not have support for transactions.

You can however use the Backport of the Drupal 7 DB API: http://drupal.org/project/dbtng